# TensorFlow Federated Python package from source in google colab

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-colaboratory, bazel, tensorflow-federated

Hello I am trying to install tensorflow_federated from scratch by its source code in google colab with the instructions from [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/federated/blob/master/docs/install.md#build-the-tensorflow-federated-python-package-from-source) in order to execute the examples and the tests from the source code

I installed bazel in google colab with the following commands

```
BAZEL_VERSION = '0.20.0'

!wget https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/releases/download/{BAZEL_VERSION}/bazel-{BAZEL_VERSION}-installer-linux-x86_64.sh

!chmod +x bazel-{BAZEL_VERSION}-installer-linux-x86_64.sh

# !export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/bin:/root/bin"
```

and when i type

```
!bazel
```

the output seems fine

But when I try to install tensorflow federated with instructions mentioned above i get an error

more particularly when i type

```
bazel run //tensorflow_federated/tools/development:build_pip_package -- \
    --nightly \
    --output_dir "/tmp/tensorflow_federated"
```

I get the following output

```
INFO: Invocation ID: d0ba7553-9587-4f7e-a388-cf77e71fa004
INFO: Options provided by the client:
  Inherited 'common' options: --isatty=1 --terminal_columns=0
INFO: Reading rc options for 'build' from /content/federated/.bazelrc:
  Inherited 'common' options: --announce_rc
INFO: Reading rc options for 'build' from /content/federated/.bazelrc:
  'build' options: --compilation_mode=opt --define=use_fast_cpp_protos=true --copt=-march=native --host_copt=-march=native --copt=-O3
Loading: 
Loading: 0 packages loaded
ERROR: Skipping '-output_dir': no such target '//:-output_dir': target '-output_dir' not declared in package '' defined by /content/federated/BUILD
Loading: 2 packages loaded
ERROR: no such target '//:-output_dir': target '-output_dir' not declared in package '' defined by /content/federated/BUILD
Loading: 2 packages loaded
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.233s
Loading: 2 packages loaded
INFO: 0 processes.
Loading: 2 packages loaded
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully (2 packages loaded)
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully (2 packages loaded)
```

And when i want to import tensorflow federated i get this output

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'computation_pb2' from 'tensorflow_federated.proto.v0' (/content/federated/tensorflow_federated/proto/v0/__init__.py)
```

Can somebody help me  ?
Thank you in advance

Comment: Looks like `--` does not work, and both arguments are interpreted by the bazel instead of the `build_pip_package`. For sake of sanity try an one liner: `bazel run //tensorflow_federated/tools/development:build_pip_package --  --nightly --output_dir "/tmp/tensorflow_federated"`